# how to get ajax data with jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery

i try using jquery ajax to get content from :

`http://www.infovesta.com/isd/free/reksa2.jsp?tipe=pt&_=1332749661789`

that url is contained data from `h**p://www.infovesta.com/isd/index.jsp`

after checking by firebug on my working page, i get http response 200 but data is not loaded,
but comparing to their site, they can get the data with that request url.

what's the step i missed?

my code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://www.infovesta.com/isd/free/reksa2.jsp?tipe=pt&_=1332749661789',
          success: function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
          }
        });     
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: By the looks of it, they limit the data to their own server (so an external call wont work, like you are trying to do.) try copying the url to the browser and see, you get no data back. so its not your script that does not work.

Comment: What do you have displayed in response?

Comment: ya nothing appeared on my browser if i open it directly

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are calling another domain and you have a problem with [same domain policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Does that site support jsonp?If so you should do

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.infovesta.com/isd/free/reksa2.jsp?tipe=pt&_=1332749661789',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
      }
    });
```

Setting the dataType to jsonp does the following

> Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the
>   end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending
>   a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache
>   option is set to true.

Comment: how to know if they provide jsonp?

Comment: @kreamik you should either try it or look at the documentation of the site